# Multiple vue popover on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, element-ui

I added vue **Element UI** library for component, its work fine for a single instance, but when I used it several or more than one time its not working!

Here are the details overview

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      visible: false
    };
  }
};
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.12.0/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.12.0/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
 

<div>
   <el-popover
    ref="popover"
    placement="right"
    title="Title"
    width="200"
    trigger="hover"
    content="this is content, this is content, this is content">
    
 
  </el-popover>
   <el-button v-popover:popover>Focus to activate</el-button>
</div>
    
    <br/><br/>
    
<div>
   <el-popover
    ref="popover1"
    placement="right"
    title="Title"
    width="200"
    trigger="hover"
    content="this is content, this is content, this is content">
    
 
  </el-popover>
   <el-button v-popover:popover1>Focus to activate</el-button>
</div>
 

 
</template>
</div>
```

ID must be unique for each popover
https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/installation

Comment: Have you tried using a unique ref for each popover element? It appears that you are getting all popups at same time due to the same ref.

Comment: No, I don't know how to do this?

Comment: Try the suggestion and see if it works. But from docs it looks like it's the reference

Answer (score 4):

Your `reference` must be unique.

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      visible: false
    };
  }
};
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.12.0/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.12.0/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
 

<div>
   <el-popover
    ref="popover"
    placement="right"
    title="Title"
    width="200"
    trigger="hover"
    content="this is content, this is content, this is content">
    
 
  </el-popover>
   <el-button v-popover:popover>Focus to activate</el-button>
</div>
    
    <br/><br/>
    
<div>
   <el-popover
    ref="popover2"
    placement="right"
    title="Title"
    width="200"
    trigger="hover"
    content="this is content, this is content, this is content">
    
 
  </el-popover>
   <el-button v-popover:popover2>Focus to activate</el-button>
</div>
 

 
</template>
</div>
```

Comment: Fine! If I have infinite component so how can I handle `ref="popover2" ` attribute ?

Comment: Of course you will have unique ID for each. I'm sure you'd be using an array of some sort to populate the list and indexes can provide uniqueness to each of your elements.

Comment: @Momin u can use `key` in `v-for` to generate unique `ref`. or use the `<el-button slot="reference">Click to activate</el-button>` inside `el-popover` and remove `ref`. [example](https://codepen.io/alireza-safian/pen/BaBYOrO)